# How to get odd or even lines from a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

How to get odd or even lines from a two-dimensional array?

```
String myData [][] = {
        {"test1","test1","test1","test1"},
        {"test2","test2","test2","test2"},
        {"test3","test3","test3","test3"},
        {"test4","test4","test4","test4"},
        {"test5","test5","test5","test5"},
        {"test6","test6","test6","test6"}
    };
```

And write them into 1 or 2 new arrays.
Need to get:

```
String oddLines [][] = { 
    {"test1","test1","test1","test1"},
    {"test3","test3","test3","test3"},
    {"test5","test5","test5","test5"}};

String evenLines [][] = { 
    {"test2","test2","test2","test2"},
    {"test4","test4","test4","test4"},
    {"test6","test6","test6","test6"}};
```

myData Array size unknown, maybe <5 , <6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use math. You know that there will be half even and half odd. You can use that and a loop to copy the values from the original array to the new arrays. Something like,

```
String[][] evenLines = new String[myData.length / 2][];
String[][] oddLines = new String[myData.length - evenLines.length][];
for (int i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    oddLines[i / 2] = myData[i];
    if (i + 1 < myData.length) {
        evenLines[i / 2] = myData[i + 1];
        i++;
    }
}
System.out.printf("oddLines: %s%n", Arrays.deepToString(oddLines));
System.out.printf("evenLines: %s%n", Arrays.deepToString(evenLines));
```

Outputs

```
oddLines: [[test1, test1, test1, test1], [test3, test3, test3, test3], [test5, test5, test5, test5]]
evenLines: [[test2, test2, test2, test2], [test4, test4, test4, test4], [test6, test6, test6, test6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use modulo. In java generally, to check if a number is even or odd, you use modulo.
`var % 2 == 0` returns if `var` is even. so you can use it like this:

```
String myData [][] = {
        {"test1","test1","test1","test1"},
        {"test2","test2","test2","test2"},
        {"test3","test3","test3","test3"},
        {"test4","test4","test4","test4"},
        {"test5","test5","test5","test5"},
        {"test6","test6","test6","test6"}
};
List<String[]> evenLines = new ArrayList<>();
List<String[]> oddLines = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) evenLines.add(myData[i]);
  else oddLines.add(myData[i]);
}
```

---

To check if it works or not:

```
System.out.print("Even lines:");
evenLines.forEach((s) -> {
    for(String string : s) System.out.print(" " + string);
});
System.out.print("\nOdd lines:");
oddLines.forEach((s) -> {
    for(String string : s) System.out.print(" " + string);
});
```

### Output:

```
Even lines:  test1 test1 test1 test1 test3 test3 test3 test3 test5 test5 test5 test5
Odd lines: test2 test2 test2 test2 test4 test4 test4 test4 test6 test6 test6 test6
```